# Hide taskbar on then second monitor when using fullscreen in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide

As I said in the title, when I enter full-screen mode in Android Studio (or other JetBrains IDEs) the taskbar on the second monitor will be shown while in the main monitor it will hide.

How can I get the same behavior on the second monitor? I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting you correctly .. and after checking linked tickets on JetBrains Issue Tracker ... it's not possible:

[IDEA-129034](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129034) and perhaps [IDEA-164559](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164559)-- watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress. Right now it does not look like these tickets are on devs "to do soon" list.